# Sequelize.js - add association on save() without fetching another object

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

Let's say I have two tables `parent` and `child`, related that `parent` has many `child`ren. All properly mapped in Sequelize. I want to add new `child` to existing `parent`. In place of addition I don't have `parent` instance available, however I have his `id` value.

I know I can always fetch proper `parent` and set in on newly created `child` instance but my question is - is it necessary? Is there a way to set just id and create valid association? I want to avoid additional SELECT.

Comment: In Hibernate (the Sequelize equivalent in Java) we can get a reference to a `parent` (entity) without actually loading it from the database. This object can then be used when persisting the `child` class. The only other way to do this (in Hibernate) is to use native SQL queries. I know this obviously doesn't answer your question but I hope it helps you when looking through the API

Comment: Thanks, actuallly I figured out the solution, I'll post it when I have more time. btw. I used Hibernate for years and Sequelize after that is pretty refreshing experience:)

Answer (score 3):

It turned out be pretty simple (although not very ORM).
I just add field `parent_id` when creating `child` instance like this:

```
child.create({
    parent_id: parentId,
    otherFields....
});
```

If relation between `parent` and `child` is defined (ex.using `belongsTo`), no additional fields in `child` model are needed.